# KDE Plasma Alt + Shift to switch keyboard layout

Tags: kde

The shortcut option in the KDE options menu doesn't seem to accept 2-key hotkeys or something. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Keyboard > Layouts > Main Shortcut.

You'll get to this page,

[image: Keyboard - System Settings]

where you can select <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Source: [Reddit - Alt + Shift to switch keyboard layout](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/ohlykx/alt_shift_to_switch_keyboard_layout/)